# Using Volley on Android to Invoke Post Call on Node.js

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, post

I am trying to make an emulated android app call a post request run by a Node.js server on the same machine.The callback method is never invoked on the Android side and the Node.js side never gets the request.

Android:

```
public void authGetRequest() {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);  // this = context
        final TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
// prepare the Auth Get Request
        String url = "10.0.2.2:3004/getTestData";
        StringRequest lastFMAuthRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // display response
                        v.setText(response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );

// add it to the RequestQueue
        queue.add(lastFMAuthRequest);
    }
```

Node.js/Server.js

```
/**
 * Required Modules
 */
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var DataBase = require('./dataBase.js');

var mysql = require("mysql");
/**
 * Setup
 */
var router = express.Router();
var path = __dirname + '/views/';
var data_base = new DataBase(mysql,'localhost','shane','devPassword');
app.use("/",router);
app.listen(3004,function(){
  console.log("Live at Port 3004");
});

/**
 * TCP calls to be used in diration of operation
 */
router.use(function (req,res,next) {
  console.log("/" + req.method);
  next();
});

router.post("/getTestData",function(req,res,next){
  console.log("Got Request");
  var testdata = {
  retrieve: true,
  rowNum: 0
}
data_base.interact(testdata,function(resp){
  res.json({name:resp.first});
  });
});
```

Exception Being Thrown:

```
E/Volley: [252] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL https//10.0.2.2:3004/getTestData
          java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL https//10.0.2.2:3004/getTestData
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:144)
              at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
           Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: https//10.0.2.2:3004/getTestData
              at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
              at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:102)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
              at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112) 
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
```

Comment: are you getting the logs in the server? I mean is the request reaches server

Comment: try url with http that is http:// 10.0.2.2:3004/getTestData

Comment: @arjun_sna There are no requests from the server. My terminal did not print "Got Request".